# Command not executing when invoking windows cmd from vb.net app

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.diagnostics

I'm a bit of a .NET noob. I've been struggling trying to find a way to execute a command through a vb.net application and I found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c88f61f5-7f2b-4c9b-8523-a334186fb0b9/how-to-execute-a-command-line-in-vbnet)
so what I came up with, to map a drive to another server on the network was this;

```
Dim application As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
Dim process As Process
process = process.Start(application)
Dim command As String = "net use x: \\webtest01\c$ /USER:daylight\robbery TakeItNGo" 'all fake obviously
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command)
process.WaitForExit()
process.Close()
```

but when I run app, it sits for about 30seconds and then I get the windows command console popping up with the working directory set to `E:\>`

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please, this is the first time I'm doing this from a vb.net app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code need modifications

```
    Dim application As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe") With 
                         {.RedirectStandardInput = True, .UseShellExecute = False}
    Dim process As New Process
    process = process.Start(application)
    Dim command As String = "net use x: \\webtest01\c$ /USER:daylight\robbery TakeItNGo"  _
             & vbCrLf & "exit"
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command)
    process.WaitForExit()
    process.Close()
```

To use standard input you need `.RedirectStandardInput = True, .UseShellExecute = False` ([Process.StandardInput Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x859hf2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ). And "exit" command is necessary to end the `cmd` process.

Comment: When I used direct methods it would not execute forwarding commands but "CMD" would open. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
Dim command As String = "/C net use x: \\webtest01\c$ /USER:daylight\robbery TakeItNGo" 
Dim application As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", command)
Dim process = process.Start(application)
process.WaitForExit()
process.Close()
```

The [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5zzxthe.aspx) class has a constructor that takes two arguments, the program file to start and the arguments to pass to this process.

However it is of paramount importance with CMD.exe to pass the flag `/C` on the command line otherwise the arguments will be ignored and the cmd.exe exits without looking at the arguments

[More info on CMD flags](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Of course all of this is valid if you are able to connect to the network resource with the credentials given. I would verify this as first step trying the same command on a normally opened command shell.

Comment: already checked that the command with uname and pwd works.
my intelli-sense is underlining line three in the code you replied with, should `process.Start(application)` be `Process.Start(application)` or should I instantiate the process object in the declaration?